# Initial state update using useState() is not working in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd, use-state, react-functional-component

I am trying to pass the dataSource(Array of objects)by using the useState hook in react as its initial value. Unfortunately, it is always setting to an empty Array[]. What am I doing wrong here?

```
  const ProductDataSource = dataList.map((data, i) => {
    return {
      key: data.id,
      image: (
        <Zoom>
          <ImageIcon
            style={{ width: '100px', objectFit: 'cover' }}
            src={data.images ? [data.images[0].downloadURL] : []}
          />
        </Zoom>
      ),
      product: data.name,
      price: data.hourlyRate,
      description: data.desc,
      WeekRate: data.weeklyRate,
      status: data.isApproved == 1 ? 'Approved' : data.isApproved == 0 ? 'Rejected' : 'Pending',
      isArchived: data.isArchived ? 'true' : 'false',
      isSelling: data.isSell ? 'Selling' : 'Rental',
    }
  })

  ****** Here's the useState below i'm getting an empty array from in return ******


  -> const [productData, setproductData] = useState(ProductDataSource)
  const handelDeleteProduct = (ind) => {
    setproductData(productData.filter((item) => item.key !== ind))
    console.log(productData)
  }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Where does `dataList` cone from?  How have you confirmed that it contains elements when the state is initialized?  How have you confirmed you aren't updating that state to something else right away?  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: dataList is initial state and data is passing from the firebase

Comment: If the array is empty then... the array is empty.  You're going to need to do some debugging to narrow down the problem and provide an example here which demonstrates the problem.  The answer posted below at this time is a good guess, but it's exactly that... a guess.  Without code which demonstrates the problem there is little we can do to help.

Answer (score 1):

For sure `dataList` does not contains any data at component's loading. To solve, use an `useEffect` hook with `dataList` in dep list in this way:

```
const [productData, setproductData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
   const ProductDataSource = dataList.map((data, i) => {
    return {
      key: data.id,
      image: (
        <Zoom>
          <ImageIcon
            style={{ width: '100px', objectFit: 'cover' }}
            src={data.images ? [data.images[0].downloadURL] : []}
          />
        </Zoom>
      ),
      product: data.name,
      price: data.hourlyRate,
      description: data.desc,
      WeekRate: data.weeklyRate,
      status: data.isApproved == 1 ? 'Approved' : data.isApproved == 0 ? 'Rejected' : 'Pending',
      isArchived: data.isArchived ? 'true' : 'false',
      isSelling: data.isSell ? 'Selling' : 'Rental',
    }
  })
  setproductData(ProductDataSource)
}, [dataList]);
```

Comment: @KeshavRohilla ok but if data is coming and you call a `map` inside component's body, you could get empty `dataList`. Could you show how `dataList` will be filled?

Comment: this is not what i'm looking for that dataList is already i'm using in useEffect.. My query is i want to delete a key from this dataList and below there is a delete function and useState(ProductDataSource) Hook. if you have some solution for the same kindly assist.

Comment: @KeshavRohilla but you mean the `handelDeleteProduct` function?

Comment: @KeshavRohilla If the problem is that on console.log you see `productData` not filterred is totally normal. `setproductData` is async and you cannot log the lasta value after an async call. This is how react works. If you want to see the veryy last value of `productData`, make a `useEffect` like `useEffect(() => { console.log(productData); }, [productData])`

Comment: Giovanni i want to delete the product and in useState i already pass ProductDataSource to filter that key.. but in ProductDataSource is giving empty array i dont know why it is giving me a empty array please help me out of this error